# Casting form inputs in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I seem to have a few cases where I want to accept an array of values via a form:

```
<input name="model[field][]>
<input name="model[field][]>
<input name="model[field][]>
```

But then on the server side, my "Model.field" attribute is implemented as a string.

So there will be some kind of transformation taking the array and converting it into a string.

My question is this:  Is there a way to generically handle this.

On the server side, is there a way where I can say "Whenever the form tries to assign an array to a string, use function X to do the assignment"

I realise my schema is questionable... and it's questionable to do blanket casting.... but if I HAD to do this, what would be the best method?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's Rails. You can do everything you want. If I understand you correctly: You receive an array from form and you need to save this array in database. Here are steps to do this
1) permit this attribute (you are using Rails4). Do smth like this:

```
def model_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:title, {:field => []})
end
```

2) Serialize field in database. Just put this in your model:

```
class Model
   serialize :field
end
```

Rails will handle all for you. Read more about [serialize method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize)

Comment: OK but what if I wanted it to be an automatic thing... without knowing the field name.  IE:  When ever I see an array attempting to be assigned to a string, run the serialize method.  (This is just for the form submission, not for the datatypes in general).

Comment: I can hardly imagine why you need this. If you do this your rails app can work unpredictable for other members of the team. But if you want to to this you can override attr= method in model or in active record(for all models). But I'm totally against this variant.